# MQTT publish subscribe in the same client

Tags: mqtt

My requirement is as follows:

There are multiple clients IoT devices. They send data to a server, they receive messages from server and change their behaviour. There are various front ends who want to monitor data from devices and send commands to devices.

I was reading about MQTT and understand it to have subscribers, publishers and a broker in between.

My question is, can I register my devices as publishers and subscribers to the same broker? Is this advisable? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a problem with that.

To keep things separate, you may want to use different channels for transmitting data and control messages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be no issue with MQTT publish and subscribe in the same client.

Here is a sample Java code for a MQTT Client with both Publish and Subscribe:

```
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class MQTTClient {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQTTClient.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MqttClient mqttClient;
        String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        String subscribeTopicName = "echo";
        String publishTopicName = "thing";
        String payload;
        MqttDefaultFilePersistence dataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(tmpDir);
        try {
            mqttClient = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost:1883", "thing1", dataStore);
            MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
            mqttConnectOptions.setUserName("/:guest");
            mqttConnectOptions.setPassword("guest".toCharArray());
            mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);
            mqttClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions);
            logger.info("Connected to Broker");
            mqttClient.subscribe(subscribeTopicName);
            logger.info(mqttClient.getClientId() + " subscribed to topic: {}", subscribeTopicName);
            mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                @Override
                public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
                    logger.info("Connection lost to MQTT Broker");
                }

                @Override
                public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                    logger.info("-------------------------------------------------");
                    logger.info("| Received ");
                    logger.info("| Topic: {}", topic);
                    logger.info("| Message: {}", new String(message.getPayload()));
                    logger.info("| QoS: {}", message.getQos());
                    logger.info("-------------------------------------------------");

                }

                @Override
                public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
                    logger.info("Delivery Complete");
                }
            });
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
                payload = "Message " + i + " from Thing";
                message.setPayload(payload
                        .getBytes());
                logger.info("Set Payload: {}", payload);
                logger.info(mqttClient.getClientId() + " published to topic: {}", publishTopicName);
                //Qos 1
                mqttClient.publish(publishTopicName, message);
            }
        } catch (MqttException me) {
            logger.error("reason: {}", me.getReasonCode());
            logger.error("msg: {}", me.getMessage());
            logger.error("loc: {} ", me.getLocalizedMessage());
            logger.error("cause: {}", me.getCause());
            logger.error("excep: {}", me);
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, please check **mqttClient.subscribe** for subscribe and  **mqttClient.publish** for publish.
I have explained how this works end to end with RabbitMQ as MQTT broker in a blog and the sample working code that I have used is available on GitHub. Please check: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2017/12/iot-internet-of-things-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one broker in the overall setup. For scalability reasons we may put multiple brokers which can work in unison and as a whole is always representation of a single broker.  In the multiple broker set up too, the edge client will connect to a single broker only.

Make sure you keep one unique publishing topic and one unique subscribing topic per device for the scalability of the device, lower edge processing and easy understanding of humans.

Again there are always trade offs based on the usecase.

Cheers, 
Ranjith

Comment: Being an IoT device, it could have an intermittent connection, so there needs to be a local broker or cache of some kind to store the messages while the device is offline. Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: @RomanGaufman When you have a hybrid requirement like running a local broker (or gateway) and having all the local devices connected to the local broker which can work even without an internet.  The broker will collect and store data and send it to the central server. 

On the other hand, you can have a caching mechanism in the client itself, if you have less number of devices per location.